# LCAO-MO ansatz for arbitrary hydrogenic molecule term

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration

I am struggling to understand the connection between molecular electronic term symbols and translating the symmetries to the underlying wavefunction.

In particular, my understanding of the LCAO-MO method tells me that I can write the molecular wavefunction as

$$ \Psi(r_1,r_2) = N \left( 1s_a(r_{1a})  1s_b(r_{2b}) + 1s_a(r_{1b})  1s_b(r_{2a}) \right) (\alpha(1)\beta(2)-\beta(2)\alpha(1)) \; ; $$

where the spatial part encompasses the spatial symmetry and the spin part ensures that the state is a singlet.

Independently of this, I can determine that the ground state of the hydrogen molecule has a term symbol of $^1\Sigma$: it is $\Sigma$ because both atoms contribute $l=0$ to the total $L$ quantum number, which in turn will be 0, and it is singlet because of the spin restriction.

I am fairly certain that the fact that there's a positive sign in the spatial part would be represented by a $_g$ subscript for gerade spatial symmetry - is this correct? And if I had a negative sign, I'd get the $^1\Sigma_u$ state, right?

However, if I look at the electronic states of the hydrogen molecule, [by for example looking at a list here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/002689704100016723046?journalCode=tmph20), I am not too sure what would be the LCAO-MO equivalent for the states listed.

For example what would be the ansatz for the state $^3\Sigma_u^+$ (I do not know how to account for the $^+$ for example) Or let's say for $^3\Delta_g$? And how would I treat "pre-factors" such as the term $b^3\Sigma_u^+$?

Comment: There's a pretty good summary on wikipedia. Check out the "Wigner Witmer Correlation rules" section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_term_symbol